# A minimalist block in latex beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, tikz-styles

I want to create a block that looks like: [image]

I am unable to find the latex template for the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! With `tcolorbox`?

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, I didn't know about this package before. I am yet to find the working example for this.

Comment: `boxed title` and the examples on page 161 of the `tcolorbox` manual might get you started.

Comment: `tcolorbox` manual: http://caesar.ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tcolorbox` package is the best option. The box is so minimalistic that can easly be done with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\minimalisticBox}[2]{
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rounded corners,draw,line width=1.5pt,inner sep=5ex](MBoxForm){#2};
\node[anchor=west,fill=white] at (MBoxForm.155) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}%\minimalisticBox{title}{contents}
\begin{document}
\minimalisticBox{Scattering probability}{$f_{ij}=\frac{\alpha_S^2(Q^2)}{2}\log^2[\frac{r_{14}r_{23}}{r_{24}r_{13}}]$}
\end{document}
```

[image: minimalistic box]

Comment: Thanks @vi_pa, I have been trying to find something from the tcolorbox, but it seems confusing.

Comment: I don't have used the `tcolorbox` package I've used only `TikZ`.

Comment: `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm}, colback=white!100!black,colframe=black,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,title=My title,fonttitle=\bfseries, boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white}] 
This box uses a \textit{boxed title}. The box of the title can be formatted independently from the main box. 
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

A solution in tcolorbox:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
colback=white!100!black,colframe=black,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,title=My title,fonttitle=\bfseries,boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white} ]This box uses a \textit{boxed title}. The box of the title can be formatted independently from the main box.\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image: output]

therefore for the box in question:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm}, colback=white,colframe=black,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,title={\LARGE Scattering probability},halign=flush center,fonttitle=\bfseries, boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white}] 
$f_{ij}=\frac{\alpha_S^2(Q^2)}{2}\log^2[\frac{r_{14}r_{23}}{r_{24}r_{13}}]$ 
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

[image]