# Linebreaking in tikz table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, line-breaking, tcolorbox

I want to have a line break in the text that I write inside a tikz table(example here [A minimalist block in latex beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518344/192091)). The latex code I have is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\minimalisticBoxred}[2]{
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(example-align)[red,rounded corners,draw,line width=1.5pt,inner sep=5ex](MBoxForm){#2};
\node[anchor=west,fill=white] at (MBoxForm.155) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}%\minimalisticBox{title}{contents} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\minimalisticBoxred{Tikz}{Example of text with a line break \\ Want to have a \\ line break here} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I followed few examples from [this question's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/192091) but it didn't work yet. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `align=left` to the first node I got

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\minimalisticBoxred}[2]{
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(example-align)[red,rounded corners,draw,line width=1.5pt,inner
sep=5ex,align=left](MBoxForm){#2};
\node[anchor=west,fill=white] at (MBoxForm.155) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}%\minimalisticBox{title}{contents} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\minimalisticBoxred{Ti\emph{k}Z}{Example of text with a line break \\ Want to have a \\ line break here} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general you need to specify an alignment or the `text width` to enable line breaks.

You were loading but not using `tcolorbox` in your code. Actually, I'd think that this might be better way to design the box.

Comment: Thanks, I am starting out with tikz so I missed the ```text width ``` argument. Is there any way to keep the text in the box in default text colour and only change the outline of the table to red?

Comment: @tachyon Sure. Instead of `red,rounded corners,draw` use `draw=red,rounded corners` or `draw=red,rounded corners,text=black`. (However, I still think you should consider using `tcolorbox`. The `tikzpicture` is fine, but you can't put another `tikzpicture` inside without nesting `tikzpicture`s, and so on.)

Comment: The answer in ```tcolorbox``` is ```\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm}, colback=white,colframe=red,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,title={Ti\emph{k}Z},halign=flush center,fonttitle=\bfseries, boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white}] 
Example of text with a line break \\ Want to have a \\ line break here
\end{tcolorbox} ```